# manage concurrency access mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, nosql, spring-data-mongodb

i need to manage concurrency access for data updates in mongoDB.
Example: two users a and b connect to my application. The user a has updated a data and the user b wants to update the same data that the user a has already updated, so i want the user b cannot update this data because is has already updated by the user a.

Comment: try use `compareAndSe` opreation

Comment: @TongChen please can you give me an example for using compareAndSet

Comment: Maybe have a look at the javax.persistence annotation @Version.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648515/using-version-in-spring-data-project

Answer (score 0):

if user A and user B only update one document and your can know the initial value and updated value try this code：

The code try to update the *secret* field，and we know the inital value is *expertSecret*

```
public void compareAndSet(String expertSecret, String targetSecret) {
    // get a mongodb collection
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = client.getDatabase(DATABASE).getCollection(COLLECTION);
    BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject();
    filter.append("secret", expertSecret);
    BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
    update.append("secret", targetSecret);
    collection.updateOne(filter, update);
}
```

**If don't know initial value,how to do?**

you can add a filed to representative operation,and before update check the filed.

**If need to update more than one document,how to do?**
Multi-document transactions need mongo server to support,get more information from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/)

> However, for situations that require atomicity for updates to multiple documents or consistency between reads to multiple documents, MongoDB provides the ability to perform multi-document transactions against replica sets. Multi-document transactions can be used across multiple operations, collections, databases, and documents. Multi-document transactions provide an “all-or-nothing” proposition.

Comment: thank you, I'll try to add a field and check it before doing an update. Is there a way to generate a sequence in mongodb with spring data that is auto incremented after each update or insert?

Comment: Mongodb hava a `$inc` operator you can find the same opreation in `Spring Data`