# entityManager.merge(object) is persisting only the last record from list

Tags: jpa, java-8, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I have two records in my `ArrayList<Object>` but when I'm trying to insert these records in database, only the last record gets saved into DB.

I'm using Spring data JPA `entityManager.merge()` method since I have custom sequenceGenerator to be used for Entities.

```
summaryList.stream().forEach{(summary -> entityManager.merge(summary)};
```

On debugging I get two records in summaryList but when I check my DB table, only one record gets inserted.

Comment: Have you checked your custom generator earlier? Seems it returns the same value twice.

Comment: @amseager: I didn't get. Could you please elaborate as I was able to get correct values in database earlier. The custom generator is used only for generating IDs from one of the common Sequence.

Comment: since you don't post the entity then what are you expecting? You also dont mention where transaction boundaries are, or what lifecycle state the objects to be persisted are in when calling merge.

Comment: @BillyFrost: code is shown below: public void saveTable(List<Summary> summary) {    summary.stream().forEach(sum -> entityManager.merge(sum)); } where Summary is my Entity.

Comment: Entity is below:   @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "SUM_ID_SEQ")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "SUM_ID_SEQ", strategy = "com.sbc.test.SummarySequenceIdGenerator")
  @Column(name = "SUM_ID", insertable = true, updatable = true, unique = true, nullable = false)
  private BigInteger mbrshpLdgrSumId;

  @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

Comment: put that in your QUESTION!

Comment: Can someone provide some other approach other than using @Version since we have restricted access privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate generates a `SELECT` statement first to fetch the latest state of the underlying database record, and then, it copies the detached entity state onto the newly fetched managed entity. This way, the *dirty checking mechanism* can detect any state change and propagate it to the database.

While for `IDENTITY` and `SEQUENCE` generator strategies, you can practically use merge to persist an entity, for the assigned generator, this would be less efficient.

You can actually fix this issue by adding a version property to your entity.

```
@Version
private Long version;
```

Comment: Do I need to set the value for version as well in my service layer.

Comment: My question was how will it identify the value of "version". Will that need a new column in DB table.

Comment: As I told just add @Version private Long version;  rest hibernate will take care

Comment: Getting error in select query which merge() internally fires, when added @Version since it adds a column version also which is not there in table.

Comment: Hibernate should create the column version when you restarts the server

Comment: It is not creating, maybe since Iam using Spring Data JPA. Please confirm Iam not sure though

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648515/using-version-in-spring-data-project

Comment: I agree but my only concern is whether it will go and add one more Column in my table. If that is the case, we have restriction in adding column from our side privilege restriced